# MySQL: How to select and process "n to n" related data with a view to performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, relationship

**Assignment:**
I need to select data with many to many relations and search for a solution with a good performance. I have currently two working solutions (see below).

**Example / Description:**
Competitions are promoted by organisations. A competition can have none, one or more organisations as a promoter. I need each competition only once in the result with an ID list of the promoters.

**Data structure:**
 - Table "competition": (id, name)
 - Table "organisation": (id, name)
 - Table "competition_organisation": (competitionID, organisationID)

**Required result:**
|id|name|promoter_list|
|1|UEFA Champions League|1241|
|2|FIFA World Cup|1240|
|3|FIFA World Cup Preliminaries - Africa|1240, 1242|

**Development platform:** Cold Fusion

**Database:** MySQL

**Additional notes based on given answers:**
- The primary intension of my question is finding a way to handle these kind of relations  better than i did it in the past. Competitions are just one example where i need that.
- I tried to keep it more simple and maybe i omitted one fact to much. In my application, i also need the organisation names. For that reason, i joined the organisaton table.
- A competition has more related information than i described in this example. The queries in my application uses several joins to other tables.

---

**Solution 1:**
- Query to select the competition data
- Loop over result
- Store each record in an array inside the loop
- Additional query to select the promoter for each record in the result / loop
- Add the promoter id's with another query loop to the array

**Main Query:**

```
SELECT competition.id, competition.name
FROM competition
WHERE ...
```

**Additonal promoter query inside the loop:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT organisation.id 
FROM organisation 
INNER JOIN competition_organisation 
ON competition_organisation.organisationID = organisation.id 
WHERE competition_organisation.competitionID = competition.id[currentrow]#
```

---

**Solution 2:**
- Use only one query with a sub select
- Loop over result
- Store each record in an array inside the loop

```
SELECT competition.id, competition.name,
(
    SELECT CONVERT(GROUP_CONCAT(organisation.id SEPARATOR ', ') USING utf8)
    FROM organisation
    WHERE organisation.id in 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT competition_organisation.organisationID 
        FROM competition_organisation
        WHERE competition_organisation.competitionID = competition.id
    )
) AS promoter_list
FROM competition
WHERE ...
```

---

**Solution 3 (proposed by Spencer7593):**

```
SELECT c.id, 
       c.name,
       CONVERT(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT o.id ORDER BY o.id) USING utf8) AS promoter_id_list,
       CONVERT(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT o.name ORDER BY o.id) USING utf8) AS promoter_list
FROM competition c
LEFT JOIN competition_organisation c_o ON c_o.competitionID = c.id
LEFT JOIN organisation o ON o.id = c_o.organisationID
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
```

(I changed the code a little bit and added organisation names)

---

**Solution 4 (proposed by Thorsten Kettner, optimized by Rick James):**

```
SELECT id, name,
       ( SELECT CONVERT(GROUP_CONCAT(organisationID SEPARATOR ', ') USING utf8)         
             FROM competition_organisation
             WHERE competitionID = c.id
       ) AS promoter_id_list,
       ( SELECT CONVERT(GROUP_CONCAT(organisation.name SEPARATOR ', ') USING utf8)          
             FROM competition
             left join competition_organisation on competition_organisation.competitionID = competition.id
             left join organisationen on organisationen.id = competition_organisation.organisationID
             WHERE competitionID = c.id
       ) AS promoter_list
    FROM competition AS c
```

(Also added organisation names, hopefully in the right way)

---

**Performance comparison:**

Solution 1 - 100 records: ~30ms + (100 x ~1ms) = ~130ms
Solution 1 - 1000 records: ~70ms + (1000 x ~1ms) = ~1070ms

Solution 2 - 100 records: ~5500ms
Solution 2 - 1000 records: ~48000ms

Solution 3 - 100 records: ~120ms
Solution 3 - 1000 records: ~210ms

Solution 4 - 100 records: ~110ms
Solution 4 - 1000 records: ~200ms

---

As you can see, solution 2 has a miserable performance.

- Are there options to optimize the solution 2 query to increase the performance significantly?
- Are there alternative solutions i dont have in mind?
- Or should i stay at solution 1?

---

**Conclusion:**

I've decided to take Solution 3 by Spencer. The Performance of 3 and 4 are nearly identical. But the code of 3 is easier and perfectly matches with my existing queries, especialy with thier left joins.

I am very satisfied with the result. Perfomance has been increased greatly and i need less code / files in the future.

Thank you very much for your assistance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure they expect you to show you skills doing table joins (and possibly run it all in single query). I doubt they'll base the score in the raw execution plan.

Comment: The title says 1:many, but the code and answers involve many:many -- Which is it??  1:many does not need the 3rd table !

Comment: You are right. I changed the title to "n to n". Thx for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 3:

Make use of outer join operation and a MySQL-specific `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregate function to return comma separated list of organisationid values.

```
-- SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'group_concat_max_len';
-- SET group_concat_max_len = 1048576;

SELECT c.id      AS id
     , c.name    AS name
     , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.organisationid ORDER BY p.organisationid) AS promoter_list
  FROM competition c
  LEFT
  JOIN competition_organisation p
    ON p.competitionid = c.id
 GROUP
    BY c.id
     , c.name
 ORDER
    BY c.id
     , c.name
```

Note that if the length of the string produced by `GROUP_CONCAT` exceeds `group_concat_max_len`, the string will be silently truncated to the allowed length. (No error, no warning).

Compare the byte length of the returned string to the value of the system variable to detect whether the string has been truncated.

---

The `organisation` table can also be included in the query, if there is a need or a good reason to do that.

```
SELECT c.id      AS id
     , c.name    AS name
     , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT o.id ORDER BY o.id) AS promoter_list
  FROM competition c
  LEFT
  JOIN competition_organisation p
    ON p.competitionid = c.id
  LEFT
  JOIN organisation o
    ON o.id = p.organisationid
 GROUP
    BY c.id
     , c.name
 ORDER
    BY c.id
     , c.name
```

Comment: My group_concat_max_len is currently "1024". I could need a bit more. Does it have negative effects when i increase this value? And where should i apply the command? One time in my MySQL Client for a server wide effekt? Then i must keep it in mind when we move to another server.

Comment: Plan A: perform the `SET` just before the `SELECT`.  Plan B: change it in `my.cnf`.  There is very little down-side, assuming you have enough RAM and you do use too big a value.

Comment: All right, i prefer Plan A. I will add the command inside of my <cfquery> tag directly before "select" in my .cfm file and apply it at every page request, right? And the effekt takes only effect for the following, one query?

Comment: It has effect until you disconnect.  In the case of a web page, then you should do it for each web page.  It won't hurt to do it right before this one query, even if that means doing the `SET` multiple times per connection.

Comment: The client session setting of `group_concat_max_len` is inherited from the global setting when the session starts. It can be altered at the session level. The length of the result from `GROUP_CONCAT` is also limited by `max_allowed_packet` variable. Personally, I'd perform the `SET` statement right before the `GROUP_CONCAT` is executed. If having the string truncated isn't acceptable, and I didn't do a `SET`, then I would retrieve the current value and compare the length of the returned string to the setting... to ensure the returned string is shorter than the maximum size.

Comment: I added the set command to my global config file of the application which is called at each page request. Everything works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A single query should almost always be faster then a procedure. When it is not, this may indicate a flaw in the query.

`DISTINCT` doesn't belong in an `IN` subquery. It should be up to the DBMS *how* to look up the data. An `IN` clause should also be non-correlated. If you want or need something correlated, use `EXISTS` instead. Then, why do you join the table `organisation` at all? You don't need anything from that table.

```
select c.id, c.name, co.promoter_list
from competition c
left join
(
  select 
    competitionid, 
    group_concat(organisationid separator ', ') as promoter_list
  from competition_organisation
  group by competitionid
) co on co.competitionid = c.id;
```

Comment: (See my answer for improvements on this answer.)

Comment: For the best shot at optimum performance, I'd avoid the inline view/derived table, and just do an outer join on the two tables. I'd also include an ORDER BY in the GROUP_CONCAT to make the return more deterministic. And if repeated values of organisationid aren't needed in the promoter list, I'd also add the DISTINCT keyword in the GROUP_CONCAT. (If we have some guaranteed that organisationid isn't repeated, the DISTINCT keyword can be omitted.) We should also mention that GROUP_CONCAT is an extension specific to MySQL, and the behavior when the generated string exceeds `group_concat_max_len`.

Comment: Usually one would aggregate before joining, so as to work with small intermediate results. Hence in many DBMS my solution should be optimal. However, I don't work with MySQL, and things may be different for MySQL. (Aggregation before joining also leads to cleaner queries and prevents from typical aggregation mistakes when aggreagting several tables. So this should be the preferred approach, anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

(Caveat:  This Answer contains two ways to improve on Thorsten's answer, but I have not verified that it is a valid solution to the OP's question.)

Plan A:

`LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ... )` is likely to perform poorly.

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(organisationid SEPARATOR ', ')
             FROM competition_organization
             WHERE competitionid = c.id
       ) AS promoter_list
    FROM competition AS c;
```

The `LEFT` is turned into a correlated subquery that will return `NULL` (or `''`?) when there is nothing.

Plan B:

If `LEFT` were not needed -- that is, if there will always be a list of organizations, then this rewrite is likely to be even better:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, co.promoter_list
    FROM ( SELECT competitionid,
                  GROUP_CONCAT(organisationid SEPARATOR ', ') AS promoter_list
             FROM competition_organization
             GROUP BY competitionid
         ) AS co
    JOIN competition AS c  ON c.id = co.competitionid;
```

This has the advantage of completely building all the `GROUP_CONCATs`, *then* going after `id` and `name`.

It assumes `c`: `PRIMARY KEY(id)`.

Both variants assume `co`: `INDEX(competitionid, organizationid)` in that order.

See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table for building the optimal many-to-many table.

Comment: In terms of performance, my personal preference would be to avoid both the subquery (Plan A) and the inline view/derived table (Plan B), and just do a straight outer join on the two tables. (See Solution 3 proposed in my answer.) I think that's going to be the best bet at optimum performance (given suitable indexes available).

Comment: @spencer7593 - Your technique involves the explode-implode problem of `JOIN` + `GROUP BY`.  That is, there will be a large intermediate table containing lots of columns, followed by an implosion to do the `GROUP_CONCAT`, etc.  I avoid hauling multiple copies of `name` around.  (It may not matter much for _this_ use case; in some use cases it makes a big difference.)

Comment: I agree. I'd be concerned with that particular performance pitfall if we had several "one-to-many" joins in the query e.g. if we were also  including joins to `races_checkpoints`, `races_judges`, and so on; those semi-cross joins can *really* explode the intermediate resultset. And then the pattern of doing the collapsing in an inline view/derived table can have a significant (positive) impact on performance, keeping in mind that predicates on the outer query don't get pushed down into the inline view.)

Comment: @Christian -- Would you care to resolve this debate (for your use case)?  After checking whether both Spencer's query and my query are valid, see which is faster.

Comment: @Thorsten, Spencer, RickJames: First of all, thank you for the very usefull information and examples! All 3 solutions are valid. I made a few performance tests (with disabled query cache). Here is the result:

Thorsten: ~2600ms;
Spencer: ~200-230ms;
RickJames: ~190-220ms;

I will make some further tests and respond more detailed later. Please stand by.